# Chartjs sample line chart setup doesn't show dataLabels

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, chart.js

Using the sample line chart code for Chart.js (http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#line-chart-example-usage), I am able to create a perfect Line Chart in js fiddle or on a standalone page.

The problem is, that exact same configuration code, when inserted into my project and turned into a custom Knockout binding, doesn't show the data labels that should be on the left and bottom edges of the chart. Besides that it looks exactly the same as the sample, like it should.

My code is much too complex to include here, so what I'm looking for is just random spitball ideas of what, possibly, could be causing this to happen?  Because Chartjs outputs a Canvas element I am finding it near impossible to diagnose this problem.

Thanks ahead of time for any suggestions!

Comment: is the canvas being covered by another div/s or are the labels not being drawn on the canvas?

Answer (score 0):

What a silly problem. It turns out that the default color for the labels is #666, which is the same as my background color.  I was using the wrong attribute name to change the color of the labels, the proper attribute to set the "data label" color is: scaleFontColor